# SEL * vs SEL columns

Tags: mysql

When i do a select * query where i join multiple tables am not getting any duplicates but when i select individual columns in the same query with same tables with same joins, am getting duplicate rows.

E.g.,

```
 SEL * FROM tablea a
join tableb b
on a.col1=b.col1
join table c
on b.col2=c.col2
where XXXXX --> no duplicates

sel a.col1,b.col3,c.col4
from tablea a
join tableb b
on a.col1=b.col1
join table c
on b.col2=c.col2
where XXXXX --> returns duplicates

SEL * FROM tablea a
join tableb b
on a.col1=b.col1
join table c
on b.col2=c.col2
where XXXXX --> no duplicates

sel a.col1,b.col3,c.col4
from tablea a
join tableb b
on a.col1=b.col1
join table c
on b.col2=c.col2
where XXXXX --> returns duplicates
```

Comment: update your question and add  a valid data sample  ....

Comment: Maybe some other columns in * make the duplicates rows different? And if you don't include those looks duplicates.

Comment: sel IS NOT valid sql what else is in the mix?